# Asymptotic value of a expression

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I'm currently reading a proof of an analytic lemma and at the end of the proof it is said that the expression
$$\alpha^2x_1re^{-\alpha(|x|^2+(x_1-r)^2)}[-16k+(\alpha k r^2-2M)e^{-2\alpha\theta r^2}]+\alpha e^{-\alpha (x_1-r)^2}(e^{-\alpha |x|^2}-e^{-\alpha r^2})(\alpha k r^2-C)$$
is strictly positive when $\theta=1/\alpha$ and $\alpha$ is large enough. We are considering that $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ is in a compact set, $r,k,M,C$ are constants. Does anybody understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are missing some assumptions?

Factoring the common parts and simplifying the product $\alpha \theta = 1$, the quantity is
$$
\alpha e^{-\alpha (x_1-r)^2-\alpha|x|^2} \left(
\alpha x_1 r [-16k+(\alpha k r^2-2M)e^{-2 r^2}]+(1-e^{\alpha|x|^2- \alpha r^2})(\alpha k r^2-C) \right)$$
In the first part, the dominant term as $\alpha \to \infty$ is $\alpha^2 k r^3 x_1$ which scales like $\alpha^2$. It is positive under the assumption
$$x_1>0$$
In the second part, we could have a negative term if the exponential gets large. But, if
$$|x| \leq r$$
then $(1-e^{\alpha|x|^2- \alpha r^2})(\alpha k r^2-C) = O(\alpha)$ so is negligible in front of the dominant $\alpha^2 (kr^3x_1)$ term.

Comment: yes, I think that with the domain that is given it comes implicitly these conditions